# How to use Laravel cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, laravel

I would like to use Laravel cookies but I cannot seem to make it work.

So basicaly I'd like to make the Laravel equivalent to :

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time() + 3600 * 24 * 365);
echo $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```

I used this, without success, it's not printing anything :

```
Cookie::make('TestCookie', $value, 60 * 24 * 365);
echo Cookie::get('TestCookie');
```

Same goes for

```
Cookie::queue('TestCookie', $value, 60 * 24 * 365);
echo Cookie::get('TestCookie');
```

Or

```
Cookie::forever('TestCookie', $value);
echo Cookie::get('TestCookie');
```

I'd like to do this in my BaseController __construct method :

```
if (Session::has('hash') && !Cookie::has('hash'))
{
    Cookie::queue('hash', Session::get('hash'), $this->cookieLifeTime);
}
else if (Cookie::has('hash') && !Session::has('hash'))
    Session::put('hash', Cookie::get('hash'));
else if (!Session::has('hash') && !Cookie::has('hash'))
{
    $hash = str_shuffle(sha1(uniqid()));
    Session::put('hash', $hash);
    Cookie::queue('hash', Session::get('hash'), $this->cookieLifeTime);
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cookie::make` only creates new instances of `Cookie` class.

After you created an instance you should return it with your `Response`

```
$cookie = Cookie::make('TestCookie', $value, 60 * 24 * 365);
return Response::view('view')->withCookie($cookie);
```

Also you can do the same but with `Redirect`

```
return Redirect::to('somewhere')->withCookie($cookie)
```

*PS. Note, that cookie will be available only after page restart. And it's same for `Cookie:queue(...)`*

The main difference of `Cookie:queue()` is that Laravel will automatically attach your `Cookie` at the end of current `Response`. But it's still unavailable until next request (page opening)

**Update**

As per your comments I just tested this code:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('test', 'test'));

echo (Cookie::has('test')) ? Cookie::get('test') : 'null';
```

It works fine.

**Update 2**

Try set the correct domain name in `/app/config/sessions.php`
It might help in some cases.

Comment: @Galithiel no. And actually it doesn't make much sense, that you need to get your cookie right after you set it. You can move your cookie's value to some `$variable` and access after setting a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
Cookie::queue('TestCookie', $value, 60 * 24 * 365);
echo Cookie::get('TestCookie');
```

into:

```
if (Cookie::has('TestCookie')) {
   echo Cookie::get('TestCookie');
}
else {
    Cookie::queue('TestCookie', $value, 60 * 24 * 365);
}
```

As in PHP you cannot display cookie if page hasn't been refreshed. So first you set cookie and when you reload your page you should have your cookie set and then application can display its value.